# convert intel hex file to binary in java

Tags: java, binary, embedded, hex, intel

I have a java application that receives an intel hex file that was previously produced from a binary file from an embedded device. I need to recreate the original binary file using the intel hex file. Apparently the hex file was produced using standard well known procedure. From what I understand I basically need to place the bytes in the right position based on the block offset and the address for each 32 bit hex in each line. I read the documentation for the intel hex here: [intel hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX).
Here is how the file looks like:

```
:020000040000FA                             <-- block line for offset
:10000000A0DB0010B1020000297A0000C3FE00004E <-- data line
:10001000BD02000017FF00006FFF0000000000009D <-- data line
...............
more records from the first block
...............
:10FFE0002868283D07EB041000EB0806316891B142 <-- data line
:10FFF00042F63061084402684368304828212838B6 <-- data line
:020000040001F9                             <-- second block line offset
:1000000002F0B0FC3948009539A150F82420484648 <-- data line
:1000100033682CF057F8641C062CE3DB254898382D <-- data line
...............
and so on more blocks
...............
:1079E000321014DD1A0332061A990829741CF9188A <-- data line
:1079F00003C821146B1903320F1AC108297B1A25F9 <-- data line
:047A00002001380029                         <-- unused block
:04000005000000E512                         <-- unused block
:00000001FF                                 <-- end of file
```

I tried to find a jar or a project that would convert the file but they don't produce a binary file that is equivalent to the original so I wrote a little piece of code that tries to do that:

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[512 * 1024];//fixed standard size
    byte bDefault = (byte) 0xFF;//value to fill the gaps
    Arrays.fill(bytes, bDefault);//initialize the array with default values
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int iOffset = 0;//block offset
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(FILE)));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                String strAddress = line.substring(3, 7);
                String strRecordType = line.substring(7, 9);
                String strData = line.substring(9, line.length() - 2);
                if (strRecordType.equals("04")) {//offset line
                    iOffset = Integer.parseInt(strData, 16) * 65536;//(16*4096=65536)
                } else if (strRecordType.equals("00")) {//data line
                    byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(strData);//get the bytes
                    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {//copy the bytes into the main byte array
                        bytes[iOffset + Integer.parseInt(strAddress, 16) + i] = b[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

But this code does not produce the same bytes as the original file. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?
Edit: I just want to add that each block has a maximum of 4096 lines

Comment: I see nothing obvious. I would probably do two things: add more format checks to ensure that the file parses correctly - and add checks to ensure the file actually provides data for every single byte in your array. It might well be that the file is "incomplete", not defining contents for part of the 512k.

Comment: Thank you Durandal. Yes I could add more checks. But as far as completeness is concerned, I think that's where the problem is. The file is very likely only part of the original binary file. There are parts that the hex file does not cover. Those parts must be filled with 0xFF values in my byte array. The addresses from each line tell me where to place the bytes in my array.

Comment: I suggest that you use [Intel's documentation](http://microsym.com/editor/assets/intelhex.pdf) rather then rely on Wikipedia's terse summary.

Comment: The utility SRecord http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ will do this for you (and much more), even if you need (or just want) to write your own it may be still useful to generate a binary to compare with the output of your code for verification.

Comment: Note also that iOffset + Integer.parseInt(strAddress, 16) is loop invariant, and would be better calculated once before the loop.

Comment: @Clifford. Indeed, thank you, I am just not considering any optimizations at this point. Also, thank you for SRecord, I am evaluating it. If it works, that would be awesome.

Comment: It has never failed me yet, although its usage is perhaps not straightforward.  At its simplest you need `srec_cat xxxxx.hex -fill 0xff −o xxxxx.bin −binary`.  If your hex file base address is not zero, this may generate a very large file, there are options to adjust that.

Comment: I don't doubt that it works fine. When I said I was evaluating it, I meant porting the code to Java. As I mentioned in my original post I need either a jar or a piece of Java code. I don't want to use Runtime to make native calls.

Comment: As a debugging question, you must specify the difference between the result you achieve and the desired result.  It is not enough to say that the files differ, dump them both to hex and show an early or key example of *exactly how* they differ, along with the srecords that are supposed to produce that.  Doing so may lead you to your own answer.  Or you may ultimately discover that your file has been modified, and not simply translated.  You may also want to use objcopy or another existing tool to first check this assumption.